# Why do I get this lvalue & rvalue error while using a void function in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, rvalue, lvalue

I'm working on this exercise 18.7 in *C++ Primer Plus* (6th edition):

[image]

and the code I gave was like this, using the lambda expression as required:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

const int Size = 5;

template <typename T>
void sum(std::array<double, Size> a, T& fp);

int main()
{
    double total = 0.0;

    std::array<double, Size> temp_c = {32.1, 34.3, 37.8, 35.2, 34.7};
    sum(temp_c, [&total](double w){ total += w; });
    std::cout << "total: " << total << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
void sum(std::array<double, Size> a, T& fp)
{
    for (auto pt = a.begin(); pt != a.end(); ++pt)
        fp(*pt);
}
```

After I compiled it in VSCode, an error came out:
`cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'main(int, char**)::<lambda(double)>&' to an rvalue of type 'main(int, char**)::<lambda(double)>'`. I also checked the official answer, which is virtually the same as my code and gave the same error while being compiled. I think this is because the `void` type function doesn't match the `T&` type called in template function `sum`, but how to modify the code while keeping the original `sum()` function unchanged as required in the problem? And I'm also confused why there's a *lvalue & rvalue* problem here.

Thanks in advance for any answers & explanations.

Comment: Hint: if you substitute the typedef back into the error message, it reads like `cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'T&' to an rvalue of type 'T'`. Is that more familiar? Have you tried, for example, declaring `foo(int& x)` and then calling `foo(1);`? See how the same problem occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By defining your lambda inline you have made it a temporary, an r-value.  This means that because the template takes the function pointer as a non-const ref (ugh!), there's no conversion - the rvalue cannot be bound to an l-value parameter, so it does not compile.
If you lift the lambda out into its own variable, it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

const int Size = 5;

template <typename T>
void sum(std::array<double, Size> a, T& fp);

int main()
{
    double total = 0.0;

    std::array<double, Size> temp_c = {32.1, 34.3, 37.8, 35.2, 34.7};
    auto l = [&total](double w){ total += w; };
    sum(temp_c, l);
    std::cout << "total: " << total << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
void sum(std::array<double, Size> a, T& fp)
{
    for (auto pt = a.begin(); pt != a.end(); ++pt)
        fp(*pt);
}
```

And even though the assignment explicitly says not to adapt sum(), if you turn the fp parameter into a const ref, the original temporary variable will compile too - and that would be a much more canonical C++ way of implementing this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're passing a temporary (the lambda `[&total](double w){ total += w; }`) to a function that expects a non-const lvalue reference. Those cannot bind to temporaries such as the one you're passing here.

Writing

```
template <typename T>
void sum(std::array<double, Size> a, T fp)
```

should do the trick.

As an aside, it would be better to pass the array by `const&` to avoid copying:

```
template <typename T>
void sum(const std::array<double, Size>& a, T fp)
```

EDIT: Overlooked the part where it says `sum` should not be changed. In that case store the lambda in a variable before the call to `sum` and then pass it, as pointed out in Joris Timmermans' answer. This will provide you with the necessary lvalue that the reference can bind to.

Comment: Basically the same answer as mine, posted at basically the same time  :-) Note though that the assignment says that sum cannot be modified, so the non-ideal solution here would be to assign the lambda to a variable.

Comment: Yup! I'd overlooked the part where it says `sum` cannot be modified :(